# Display WP Start bar on front page only

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I was wondering if someone could help me display the plugin [WP Start bar](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-start-bar/) only on my static frontpage. If it helps my static frontpage url is: http://zackarylundquist.westhostsite.com/portfolio/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `is_front_page();` to check if it is called on the front page, regardless of it is a static front page or the latest articles. Identify the function that is responsible for the output of the plugin and add at the start:

```
if ( ! is_front_page()) return;
```

There are wordpress hooks that get content as a paraneter where the additional output is added, in this case you have to return the original output (or it will be broken).

```
if ( ! is_front_page()) return $input;
```

Answer (score 2):

Best you can do is make slight change in  wp-content\plugins\wp-start-bar\index.php

Line number 95 replace

```
function wpstartbar_footer(){
```

by

```
function wpstartbar_footer(){ if(is_home()){
```

Line number 197

```
   just add another '}'
```

All you are doing is calling function only on home page

Comment: Thank you so much for tracking down the line I was looking for. I was able to insert "if ( ! is_front_page()) return;" recommended by Gerald right under the line you pointed out and it did the trick perfectly.